# Is there a blog article about how to buy a car in austria

Tags: car, austria

I only found articles in German like https://www.autogott.at/tipps/autokauf

I'am searching for an english version.

And are there online plattforms like this https://www.autogott.at/ 
I am searching for a new car and maybe a used car if it's in good condition.

Comment: How about reading the article in a browser that translates German-to-English on the fly? Google Chrome (and perhaps others) can do that.

Comment: Your title is supposed to say *buy*